# How do I import XSD files into IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.1?

Tags: xml, xsd, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and to creating XSD files. In the "Create Project" wizard, there is no option to create an XML project. Do I create a Java project and then try to import the files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need Java project/module type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not use IntelliJ for XML project management. It works fine if you have XML/XSD files as part of your Java/Ruby/etc. project but it is not the best suit if you just want to be working with XML.

I use the XML Tools plugin for Notepad++ on my Windows workstation for this myself. I know that Textpad for Macs also has good XML options available for it but that software is not free like Notepad. Here is a list from Wikipedia of other [XML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_editors).